# Why does foldr work on infinite lists in Haskell but foldl doesn't?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

I've been working on understanding `foldl` vs `foldr` vs `foldl'` in Haskell. I understand that the consensus is to use `foldr` when `f` is lazy in its second argument, as it mirrors the structure of the list. `foldl'` is better when we know that the entire list needs to be processed and `f` is strict in its arguments.

I'm specifically interested in a situation like this:

```
foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
```

returns `False`.

But:

```
foldl (&&) False (repeat False)
```

never completes.

The `foldr` expands to:

```
False && (False && (False && .... (False && *False*)) ... )
```

Whereas `foldl`:

```
  && (... (&& (&& *False* False) False) ...) False
```

The stars are the base case `False` passed into `fold`.

Is `foldr` able to terminate immediately because the LHS is just a single `False`, while `foldl` the single `False` is all the way on the right, and it doesn't 'check' that until it's completed processing the left hand side?

Comment: You could check your hypothesis by passing `flip (&&)`.

Comment: @luqui They both never finish with `flip (&&)`, but I'm not sure what impact `flip` has in this situation. Likewise, if my posted hypothesis is correct, I was more curious about *why* it is, and why it can't check in both cases that one argument is `False`- and so return `False` without processing the rest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at the relevant definitions (not exactly the same as the ones from the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html), but equivalent for this analysis).

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && x = x
False && _ = False

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)

foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z [] = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

Look at the opportunities that each of `foldr` and `foldl` have to yield a result.  They both yield a result immediately when given `[]`.  In the `(x:xs)` case, `foldr` also has the opportunity to yield a result if `f` returns immediately without evaluating its right argument (which is the recursive call).  `foldl` does not have this, since its outermost call is to itself, so the only time `foldl` can give any information back is in the `[]` case, which is never reached for an infinite list.

In examples like this, I find it helpful to do some manual evaluation.  Recall that Haskell's evaluation order goes outside-in: we evaluate as little as possible to get to an applicable pattern match of the outermost function application. I will italicize the next function to be evaluated in each step. `foldr` is simple:

```
  foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
= foldr (&&) False (False : repeat False)
= False && foldr (&&) False (repeat False)
= False
```

And `foldl` reveals the problem:

```
  foldl (&&) False (repeat False)
= foldl (&&) False (False : repeat False)
= foldl (&&) (False && False) (repeat False)
= foldl (&&) (False && False) (False : repeat False)
= foldl (&&) ((False && False) && False) (repeat False)
= foldl (&&) ((False && False) && False) (False : repeat False)
= foldl (&&) (((False && False) && False) && False) (repeat False)
```

and so on.  Notice that even if `(&&)` had the ability to simplify by checking either side, we would still never get the opportunity to return it since we never reach the `[]` case.

However, the order that `(&&)` evaluates its arguments *does* still matter (it evaluates the left one first, determined by pattern matching semantics).  We can `flip` the order of the arguments and see what `foldr` does:

```
ghci> foldr (flip (&&)) False (repeat False)
^CInterrupted
```

*(exercise)* Why is this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if you pass in `flip (&&)`, then `foldr ..` is the first argument to `&&`, and `False` is the second. So, I would assume it tries to evaluate its first argument. so `&&` only short ciruits on its first argument, it doesn't check to see if the second argument is the trivial case? Also, this illustrates why `foldr` is better than `foldl` here, but it's not fair to say that `&&` is 'lazy' in its second argument here, right? This is more about short circuiting than being lazy, or is the terminology the same?

Comment: @user2666425, `(&&)` is conditionally strict in its second argument.  If you want to get precise about what to call things, read about [denotational semantics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics).

Answer (score 2):

`foldr op z [1..]` creates an expression tree like this:

```
 op
 /\
1  op
   /\
  2  op
     /\
    3  .
        .
         .
```

All but a finite part of that tree is below any particular `op`, so if any of the `op`s discard their arguments (or even just their second argument), the tree is reduced to a finite size, which can be completely evaluated in a finite time.

`foldl op z [1..]` creates an expression tree like this:

```
         .
        .
       .
     op
     /\
   op  3
   /\
 op  2
 /\
z  1
```

All but a finite part of that tree is *above* any particular `op`, so even if every `op` discards both of its arguments, no finite number of reduction steps can shrink it to a finite size.

If the lists are finite, then the trees' shapes are simply mirror images of each other, but the trees constructed from infinite lists don't have that symmetry, because infinite lists don't have that symmetry: they are infinite on the right, not on the left.

Comment: and in fact, for an infinite list, `foldl` will never stop constructing the expression tree whereas `foldr` will construct only one top node and immediately pass control to the reducing function: `foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs` ; `foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)`.

Comment: @WillNess I'm trying to avoid assuming any evaluation order. An optimistic evaluator may apply `f` later in `foldr` or earlier in `foldl` than a lazy evaluator would, but the argument about the expression trees still applies.

Comment: ah, nice. maybe mention it in the answer itself? :)