# Why is it sometimes possible to fold an infinite list from the right?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have been going through the excellent [CIS 194 course](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/lectures.html) when I got stuck on Part 5 of Homework 6. It revolves around implementing the [ruler function](https://oeis.org/A007814) without any divisibility testing.

I found that it is possible to build the ruler function by continuously interspersing an accumulator with values from an infinite list.

```
nats = [0,1,2,3,..]
[3]
[2,3,2]
[1,2,1,3,1,2,1]
[0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0]
```

Then I tried implementing this algorithm for `Stream` datatype which is a list without `nil`

```hs
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons x xs) = x : streamToList xs

instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
  show = show . take 20 . streamToList

streamFromSeed :: (a -> a) -> a -> Stream a
streamFromSeed f x = Cons x (streamFromSeed f (f x))

nats :: Stream Integer
nats = streamFromSeed succ 0

interleave x (Cons y ys) = Cons x (Cons y (interleave x ys))
foldStream f (Cons x xs) = f x (foldStream f xs)
ruler = foldStream interleave nats
```

As expected, I got stackoverflow error since I was trying to fold from the right. However, I was surprised to see the same algorithm work for normal infinite lists.

```hs
import Data.List

interleave x list = [x] ++ (intersperse x list) ++ [x]
ruler = take 20 (foldr interleave [] [0..])
```

What am I missing? Why one implementation works while the other doesn't?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does foldr work on infinite lists in Haskell but foldl doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682067/why-does-foldr-work-on-infinite-lists-in-haskell-but-foldl-doesnt)

Comment: `foldr` doesn’t exactly fold from the right, it *associates* to the right, i.e. `foldr f z [1 .. 3]` = ``1 `f` (2 `f` (3 `f` z))`` = `f 1 $ f 2 $ f 3 $ z`. If `f` is lazy in its 2nd param, it can work on an infinite stream & produce results incrementally. Likewise, lazy `foldl` (instead of strict `foldl'`) is okay with a function lazy in its 1st param. The problem is using the wrong strictness—giving a function strict in param 1 to `foldl` or in param 2 to `foldr`—so it needs to force all the way to the end of the stream to start producing results. For an infinite stream, there is no such end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `interleave` is insufficiently lazy. The magic thing that right folds must do to work on infinite structures is to not inspect the result of the folded value too closely before they do the first bit of computation. So:

```
interleave x stream = Cons x $ case stream of
    Cons y ys -> Cons y (interleave x ys)
```

This produces `Cons x _` before inspecting `stream`; in contrast, your version requires `stream` to be evaluated a bit before it can pass to the right hand side of the equation, which essentially forces the entire fold to happen before any constructor gets produced.

You can also see this in your list version of `interleave`:

```
interleave x list = [x] ++ intersperse x list ++ [x]
```

The first element of the returned list (`x`) is known before `intersperse` starts pattern matching on `list`.

Answer (score 5):

We can inspect the source code of [`foldr` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr). A less noisy version looks like:

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Haskell does *not* evaluate eagerly. This thus means that, unless you *need* `(foldr f z xs)`, it will not evaluate the accumulator. This thus means that `f` does not need the second parameter, for example because the first item `x` has a certain value, it will not evaluate the accumulator.

For example if we implement `takeWhileNeq`:

```
takeWhileNeq a = foldr f []
    where f x xs -> if x == a then [] else (x:xs)
```

if we thus run this on a list `takeWhileNeq 2 [1,4,2,5]`, then it will not evaluate *anything*. If we however want to print the result it will evaluate this as:

```
   f 1 (foldr f [4,2,5])
```

and `f` will inspect if `1 == 2`, since that is not the case, it will return `(x:xs)`, so:

```
-> 1 : foldr f [4,2,5]
```

so now it will evaluate `4 == 2`, and because this is false, it will evaluate this to:

```
-> 1 : (4 : foldr f [2,5])
```

now we evaluate `2 == 2`, and since this is `True`, the function returns the empty list, and *ingores* the accumulator, so it will never look at `foldr f [5]`:

```
-> 1 : (4 : [])
```

For an infinite list, it will thus also result an empty list and ignore folding the rest of the list.